# Displaying an image from a SharePoint list using Javascript building strings

Tags: javascript, query, json

I have a JavaScript page querying a SharePoint list. It's displaying the results on a HTML page. Now I need to display an image for each item. I've uploaded an image to a Library called Device Images and the copied the URL into a column called DeviceImage in the queried SharePoint list. So now I'm trying to get the image to display by building a string, but I'm pretty new to this so don't know the syntax.

The relevant lines are:

```
var imgDevicePicture = "";

var DeviceImage = item.Picture;

imgDevicePicture = "<p"> + DeviceImage + "</p>";
```

and where I think I need help:

```
$('#deviceimage').append(imgDeviceImage);
```

Full Javascript and HTML below

```
function getDeviceDetails() {
var txtTitle = "";
var txtOverview = "";
var txtAccessories = "";
var txtDevicetype = "";
var txtTypicalDeviceUsage ="";
var txtKnownSystemIssues ="";
var txtLifeCycles = "";
var txtTrafficlight = "";
var imgDevicePicture = "";
var tempLCS2 = "";

var query = "http://xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/Devices?$expand=LifeCycleStatus&Priority&$filter=Id eq " + window.DeviceId + "";

var call = $.ajax({
        url: query,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
        }       
    });
call.done(function (data,textStatus, jqXHR){
$.each(data.d.results, function(index, item) {
        var tempID = item.Id;
        var tempTitle = item.Title;
         var LifeCycleStart = item.DeviceAvailableFrom;
        var LifeCycleStatus = item.LifeCycleStatusValue;
        var DeviceOverView = item.Description;
        var AccessDetails = item.Accessories;
        var DeviceKind = item.Devicetype;
        var Usage = item.TypicalUsage;
        var DevicePriority = item.PriorityValue;
        var DeviceImage = item.Picture;



        txtTitle = "<p>" + LifeCycleStart + "</p><p>" + LifeCycleStatus + "</p>";
        txtOverview = "<p>" + DeviceOverView + "</p>";
        txtAccessories = "<p>" + AccessDetails + "</p>";  
        txtDevicetype = "<p>" + DeviceKind  + "</p>";
        txtTypicalDeviceUsage = "<p>" + Usage + "</p>";
        txtTrafficlight = "<p>" + DevicePriority + "</p>";
        imgDevicePicture = "<p"> + DeviceImage + "</p>";

    });
    $('#devicedetails').append($(txtTitle));  
    $('#deviceoverview').append($(txtOverview));
    $('#devicekind').append(txtDevicetype);
    $('#deviceacc').append(txtAccessories);
    $('#deviceuse').append(txtTypicalDeviceUsage);
    $('#devicestatus').append(txtTrafficlight);
    $('#imageContainer').append("<img src='/sites/IT/SiteAssets/"+txtTrafficlight.replace(/<[^>]*>/g, '')+".png' />");
    $('#deviceimage').append(imgDeviceImage);


});





call.fail(function (jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown){
    alert("Error retrieving data: " + jqXHR.responseText);
});
}
```

HTML

```
   <html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"   
      xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882"><head>

    <script src="/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/scripts/moment.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDevices.js"></script>
    <script  
    src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceDetails.js"></script>

      <script  
    src="/sites/it/SystemInventory/SiteAssets/getDeviceKnownIssues.js"></script>



     <script type="text/javascript">

     function parseQueryString(queryString)
     {
    var params = {}, queries, temp, i, l;
    queries = queryString.split("&");
    for ( i = 0, l = queries.length; i < l; i++ ) {
        temp = queries[i].split('=');
        params[temp[0]] = temp[1];
    }
    return params;
     }

     $(document).ready(function(){
    function getDeviceID() {
        if(typeof parseQueryString === "function") {
            if(window.location.href.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
                var qs = parseQueryString(window.location.href.split("?")[1])
                window.DeviceId = qs.did;
                getDeviceDetails();
                getDeviceKnownIssues();
            }
        }
    }
    getDeviceID();
    getDevices();

     });


     </script>

      <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>
     <mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
      <mso:_dlc_DocId msdt:dt="string">ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocId>
      <mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid msdt:dt="string">1d6007ea-9e58-4298-b2d6-  
       9196e2678ea3</mso:_dlc_DocIdItemGuid>

      <mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl msdt:dt="string">http://collaboration-  
        dev.norgine.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/_layouts/DocIdRedir.aspx?

       ID=ITDOCUMENTS-135-47, ITDOCUMENTS-135-47</mso:_dlc_DocIdUrl>

       </mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
      </xml><![endif]-->
       </head>
       <style type="text/css">
        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}

        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:16px;padding:10px   
        5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word- 
       break:normal;}

       .tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}


          </style>
      <table>
    <table class="tg">
     <tr>

    <td rowspan="3" class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Devices</h2>
     <div id="devices"></div>



     </td>


    <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Devise Details</h2> 
    <div id="deviceimage">
    <div id="devicedetails">

        </div></td>


       <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Specification</h2>

     <div id="deviceoverview">
         <div id="devicekind">  
             <div id="deviceimage">
        </div></td>




      </tr>
       <tr>
                 <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Known Issues</h2> 
           <div id="knowntitle">
          </div> 
          <input type=button     


      onClick="location.href=XXXX/it/SystemInventory/Lists/Knownissues/NewForm.aspx?Source=http%3A%2F%2Fcollaboration%2Ddev%2Enorgine%2Ecom%2Fsites%2Fit%2FSystemInventory%2FLists%2FKnownissues%2FAllItems%2Easpx&RootFolder='" value='Submit a known issue '> 


           </td>



       <td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Accessories </h2> 
     <div id="deviceacc"></div></td>



  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2" td class="tg-yw4l"><h2>Typical Usage</h2> 
 <div id="deviceuse"><//img id="light" class="red" src="red.gif">
        </div></td>
 <tr>
    <td colspan="3" td class="tg-yw4l" width="100"><h2>Current Status</h2> 
    <div id="devicestatus"> 
      <div id="imageContainer">
        </div></td>

    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ID`'s should be unique,, use `class` if you want to use the same properties on multiple elements.

In HTML Change `<div id="deviceimage">` to `<div class="deviceimage">`

In JS Change `imgDevicePicture = "<p"> + DeviceImage + "</p>";` to

```
imgDevicePicture = "<img src='" + DeviceImage + "'>";
```

And change `$('#deviceimage').append(imgDeviceImage);` to `$('.deviceimage').append(imgDevicePicture);`

**EDIT**

If a column is called DeviceImage try `item.DeviceImage` instead `item.Picture`

Comment: Cheers. I think that's close! When I add this code I get a the x placeholder and when I click on the image properties I get: http://collaboration-xxx.com/sites/it/SystemInventory/SitePages/undefined

Comment: The URL of the imageis http://collaboration-xxx/sites/it/SystemInventory/Device%20images/LAPTOP.jpg

Comment: Try console.log("DeviceImage: "+DeviceImage); console.log("imgDevicePicture: "+imgDevicePicture); and see image url

Comment: Done. In Console I'm getting:

DeviceImage: undefined  getDeviceDetails.js:77:13
imgDevicePicture: <img src='undefined'>

Comment: If a column is called DeviceImage try item.DeviceImage instead item.Picture